# AMWS s3 bucket image url

Tags: amazon-s3

I am using AMWS s3 in a ruby on rails project to store images for my models. Everything is working fine. I was just wondering if it *okay/normal* that if someone right clicks an image, it shows the following url:

> https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/photo/picture/100/batman.jpg

Is this a hacking risk, letting people see your bucket name? I guess I was expecting to see a bunch of randomized letters or something. /Noob

Comment: Yes it is. You can create a short URL if you want.

Comment: @OhadM, no, a short URL will necessarily redirect to the real URL, and anyone who wants to know it can just as easily see it.   Also, the assertion that revealing the bucket name is a security risk is dubious, and needs to be justified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's normal.

It's not a security risk unless your bucket permissions allow unauthenticated actions like uploading and deleting objects by anonymous users (obviously, having the bucket name would be necessary if a malicious user wanted to overwrite your files) or your bucket name itself provides some kind of information you don't want revealed.

If it makes you feel better, you can always associate a CloudFront distribution with your bucket -- a CloudFront distribution has a default hostname like d1a2b3c4dexample.cloudfront.net, which you can use in your links, or you can associate a vanity hostname with the CloudFront distribution, like assets.example.com, neither of which will reveal the bucket name.

But your bucket name, itself, is not considered sensitive information.  It is common practice to use links to objects in buckets, which necessarily include the bucket name.